# why i failed to join two dataframes when using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

l=[(1,10),(2,5), (3,7)]
l2=[(1,5), (2,6), (3,8)]
l3=[(2,3), (1,9), (3,9)]

d1=DataFrame(l)
d2=DataFrame(l2)
d3=DataFrame(l3)

j1=d1.join(d2, how='left')
```

**failed with error**: Exception: **columns overlap: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype=int64)**

**what's wrong? what happened?**

```
In [40]: d1
Out[40]:
   0   1
0  1  10
1  2   5
2  3   7

In [41]: d2
Out[41]:
   0  1
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  8
```

what i need is to join d1 and d2 using the first colum, the result should be, **which kind of DataFrame operation is needed?**

```
   0   1 2
0  1  10 5
1  2   5 6
2  3   7 8
```

Answer (score 2):

That won't work it looks what you want to do is to add just the last column which you could achieve using `concat`:

```
In [15]:
# just add the last column
j1=pd.concat([d1,d2[[1]]],axis=1)
j1
Out[15]:
   0   1  1
0  1  10  5
1  2   5  6
2  3   7  8

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

or you should `merge`:

```
In [19]:    
j1 = d1.merge(d2, how='left', on=[0])
j1
Out[19]:
   0  1_x  1_y
0  1   10    5
1  2    5    6
2  3    7    8

[3 rows x 3 columns]

In [20]:
# now rename the columns that clashed
j1.rename(columns={'1_x':'1', '1_y':'2'}, inplace=True)
j1
Out[20]:
   0   1  2
0  1  10  5
1  2   5  6
2  3   7  8

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

If we analyse what went wrong with the join, you have a clash of columns which it cannot resolve unless you specify a suffix:

```
In [42]:

j1=d1.join(d2, how='left',lsuffix='', rsuffix='_y')
j1
Out[42]:
   0   1  0_y  1_y
0  1  10    1    5
1  2   5    2    6
2  3   7    3    8

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

We can now drop the superfluous column `0_y` and rename the added column:

```
In [43]:

j1.drop(labels=['0_y'],axis=1,inplace=True)
j1.rename(columns={'1_y':'2'},inplace=True)
j1
Out[43]:
   0   1  2
0  1  10  5
1  2   5  6
2  3   7  8

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: what is the difference between d2[[1]] and d2[1] which is the same as d2.get(1) ?

Comment: The first returns a dataframe, the second a series